# How to convert ObjectProperty<Date> to ObjectProperty<LocalDate>

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to bind

`dp_date_add.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.forDateProperty());`

where `forDateProperty()` is:

```
public ObjectProperty<Date> forDateProperty() {
        if(forDate == null){
            forDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        return forDate;
    }
```

The problem is `bindBiderectional` accpets only `LocalDate`. I've tried this:

```
dp_date_add.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.forDateProperty().get().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
```

But it doesn't works, because it convert to LocalDate, not to Property LocalDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to fix this, if you can, is to change the model so it uses an `ObjectProperty<LocalDate>`. Assuming you can't do that, you need to use two listeners:

```
dp_date_add.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldDate, newDate) -> 
    model.forDateProperty().set(Date.from(newDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));

model.forDateProperty().addListener((obs, oldDate, newDate) -> 
    dp_date_add.setValue(model.forDateProperty().get().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()));
```